# How can I simulate these two droplet?

Tags: 2d, directx9, simulations, water

Below is a two droplet merging together,in 2d.
I want to simulate the behavior when I exert `combination force`(through mouse or fling force on touch screen) on one of them to 
make them to be a larger droplet.
I suppose there exists some kind of function by the distance of these two droplet's center,when the distance is closer,one becomes smaller,the other one becomes larger.
What kind of model should I build? Particles or geometry circles or sth else?

[image: Two droplet merge]

Comment: @Byte56 thanks.The post you have pointed has quite a lot on `Unity3d` and `shaders` and effects which is overhead and not necessary in my case.The key point I beg to know is the final `contour` shape during the process with user's interaction.

Comment: That other question is fundamentally the same, and the solutions are language- and framework-angostic.  A complete DX9 implementation won't be provided in any case.

Comment: @zionpi Well, there are others: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/76120/2d-metaball-liquid-effect-how-to-feed-output-of-one-rendering-pass-as-input-to?lq=1 http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/81361/surface-creation-algorithm-using-points-cloud?lq=1 Basically the answer is metaballs.