# How to fuse 2 sprites as they approach each other in Unity2D?

Tags: unity, shaders, sprites

Hi i seen this video by Sebastian Lague on ray marching. Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cp5WWtMoeKg&t=204s At 3:19 mins.

[image: How the effect look in 3D]

I want this merging effect but for 2D sprites. Please can someone instruct me on how it can be made or the steps to make it.

Comment: Use 3D effect with top-down view

Comment: Do [past Q&As](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/76153/39518) on [2D metaball effects](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/69252/39518) cover the kind of thing you want to create? I used this recently in my jam game [The Weather Inside](https://dmgregory.itch.io/weather-inside), as one example of the kind of thing you can do with this in 2D. If that's not what you need, can you edit your question to show a more specific example of what you want your 2D effect to look like?

Comment: yes it is the effect that am looking for but mine will not use complex textures. It will only use basic colours. I have read the paper but am not sure how to apply the mechanics. Can you point to some tutorials that teaches the basics of mesh generations and things that may help. Thanks.